# Using an "Or" statement in Excel when concatenating strings

Tags: excel, formulas

I have the following formula:

```
VLOOKUP(IF($AH$3="all",CONCATENATE($AH$1,$AH$6,"summary",$B6),CONCATENATE($AH$1,$AH$6,$AH$3,$B6)),tbldimCommtBase[[Concate]:YTDVariance:]],2,0)
```

Is it possible to add an "or" clause someone in the concatenated string? So, theoretically it would do this:

```
 CONCATENATE($AH$1,**$AH$6 or "ALL"**,"summary",$B6)
```

I'm new to this.

Comment: OR meaning what? use AH6 .. unless it's empty, then use "ALL" ?  under what conditions when you use 1 or the other ?

Comment: AH6 is a filtered field containing 2 options: "main campus" and "commerical". However, if both options are selected then "all" options are selected. I want the concatenated string to either pull in the two options or all options. Make sense?

Comment: What value does AH6 have when "both options are selected" ??

Comment: I figured it out. I just nested another IF statement like this:       VLOOKUP(IF($AH$3="all",CONCATENATE($AH$1,
(IF($AH$6="All", "All", $AH$6)),"summary",$B30),CONCATENATE($AH$1,$AH$6,$AH$3,$B30)),tbldimCommtContr[[Concate]:[YTD Variance:]],2,0),"

Comment: This: `IF($AH$6="All", "All", $AH$6)` does the same thing as just : `$AH$6`